# Type 'JsonDocumentSnapshot' is not a Subtype of Usermodel?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, cloud

**Type 'JsonDocumentSnapshot' is not a Subtype of Usermodel ?**

**i have highlighted my problem in source code and the problem coming from chat.dart file ..**
in flutter firebase chat application when i goes to users chat screen where users chat show in there problem creating ?

chat.dart file ...............

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:glider/chat_room.dart';
import 'account.dart';

class Chat extends StatefulWidget {
   Chat({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Chat> createState() => _ChatState();
}

class _ChatState extends State<Chat> {
  final currentUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[300],
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('users')
            .doc(currentUser!.uid)
            .collection('chats')
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
            return const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          } if (snapshot.data!.docs.isEmpty) {
            return const Center(
              child: Text("No Chats"),
            );
          } else if (snapshot.hasData){
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
                itemBuilder: (context , index) {

                var friendId = snapshot.data!.docs[index].id;
                var lastMessage = snapshot.data!.docs[index]['last_message'];
                return FutureBuilder(
                  future: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(friendId).get(),
                    builder: (BuildContext context ,AsyncSnapshot snapshot ) {
                      **var DocData = snapshot.data;**
                    if (snapshot.hasData) {
                     var friend = snapshot.data;
                     return ListTile(
                       onTap:(){
                         Navigator.push(context,
                             MaterialPageRoute
                               (builder: (context) =>
                                 Chatroom(
                                     **userModel: DocData,**
                                     friendName:friend['name'] ,
                                     friendEmail: friend['email'],
                                     friendId: friend['uid'],
                                 ),
                             ),
                         );
                       },
                       title: Text(friend!['name']),
                       subtitle: Text(lastMessage),
                       leading: Container(
                         height: 45,
                         width: 45,
                         decoration: BoxDecoration(
                           borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                           color: Colors.white
                         ),
                         child:const Center(
                           child: Icon(Icons.person,color: Colors.grey,),
                         ),
                       ),
                     );
                    }
                    return Container();
                    }
                );
                }
            );
          }
          return Container();
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => const Account(),
            ),
          );
        },
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        elevation: 8,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
        ),
        child: const Icon(Icons.add, color: Colors.white, size: 30),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and second chatroom.dart

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'toast.dart';
import 'user_model.dart';

class Chatroom extends StatefulWidget {
  UserModel userModel;
  String friendName;
  String friendEmail;
  String friendId;

  Chatroom(
      {Key? key,
      required this.userModel,
      required this.friendName,
      required this.friendEmail,
      required this.friendId})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Chatroom> createState() => _ChatroomState();
}

class _ChatroomState extends State<Chatroom> {
  final currentUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
  void sendMessage() async {
    final message = _controller.text;
    try {
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('users')
          .doc(currentUser!.uid)
          .collection('chats')
          .doc(widget.friendId)
          .collection('messages')
          .add({
        'senderId': currentUser!.uid,
        'receiverId': widget.friendId,
        'message': message,
        'time': FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
      }).then((value) {
        _controller.clear();
        FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('users')
            .doc(currentUser!.uid)
            .collection('chats')
            .doc(widget.friendId)
            .set({
          'last_message': message,
        });
      });
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('users')
          .doc(widget.friendId)
          .collection('chats')
          .doc(currentUser!.uid)
          .collection('messages')
          .add({
        'senderId': currentUser!.uid,
        'receiverId': widget.friendId,
        'message': message,
        'time': FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
      }).then((value) {
        _controller.clear();
        FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('users')
            .doc(widget.friendId)
            .collection('chats')
            .doc(currentUser!.uid)
            .set({
          'last_message': message,
        });
      });
    } on FirebaseException catch (ex) {
      Show().toast('${ex.message}');
    }
  }

  final _controller = TextEditingController();
  final uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;
  final systemColor = const SystemUiOverlayStyle(statusBarColor: Colors.transparent);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(systemColor);
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[400],
      appBar: AppBar(
        titleSpacing: 0,
        elevation: 0,
        title: Row(
          children: [
            Container(
              height: 40,
              width: 40,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15), color: Colors.white),
              child: const Center(
                child: Icon(Icons.person, color: Colors.grey),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(width: 10),
            Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text(
                  widget.userModel.name,
                  style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                      fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                ),
                Text(
                  widget.userModel.email,
                  style: GoogleFonts.lato(fontSize: 12),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: StreamBuilder(
              stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                  .collection('users')
                  .doc(currentUser!.uid)
                  .collection('chats')
                  .doc(widget.friendId)
                  .collection('messages')
                  .orderBy('time', descending: true)
                  .snapshots(),
              builder: (BuildContext context,
                  AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                  return const Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                } else if (snapshot.data!.docs.isEmpty) {
                  return Center(
                    child: Text(
                      'No chats found',
                      style: GoogleFonts.lato(color: Colors.black54),
                    ),
                  );
                } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  return ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      reverse: true,
                      itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        bool isMe = snapshot.data!.docs[index]['senderId'] == currentUser!.uid;
                        return Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: isMe
                              ? MainAxisAlignment.end
                              : MainAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
                              margin: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
                              constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 200),
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius: isMe 
                                    ? const BorderRadius.only(
                                  topLeft: Radius.circular(25),
                                  bottomLeft: Radius.circular(25),
                                  bottomRight: Radius.circular(25)
                                ) 
                                    : const BorderRadius.only(
                                  topRight: Radius.circular(25),
                                  bottomRight: Radius.circular(25),
                                  bottomLeft: Radius.circular(25)
                                ),
                                color: isMe ? Colors.blue[900] : Colors.red[400],
                              ),
                              child: Text(
                                snapshot.data!.docs[index]['message'],
                                style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                    fontSize: 16
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        );
                      });
                } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return const Center(
                    child: Text('something went wrong'),
                  );
                } else {
                  return Container();
                }
              },
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            height: 50,
            width: double.infinity,
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
            child: TextFormField(
              controller:_controller,
              style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600, color: Colors.black54),
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: InputBorder.none,
                hintText: 'Send a message . . ',
                prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.file_present_rounded),
                suffixIcon: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: sendMessage,
                    child: const Icon(Icons.near_me, color: Colors.blue)),
                hintStyle: GoogleFonts.lato(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600, color: Colors.black54),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

an the last my usermodel.dart file.....................................

```
class UserModel{
  late String name;
  late String email;
  late String password;
  late String uid;

  UserModel({
    required this.name,
    required this.email,
    required this.password,
    required this.uid,
});

  Map<String,dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'name': name,
      'email':email,
      'password':password,
      'uid':uid,
    };
  }

  UserModel.fromMap(Map<String,dynamic> fromMap) {
    name = fromMap['name'];
    email = fromMap['email'];
    password = fromMap['password'];
    uid = fromMap['uid'];
  }

}
```

here's all the

Comment: could you include the result of print('DocData=$DocData');

Comment: nothing giving any output

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `data()` to read the `Map` of data.

```dart
snapshot.data.data() as Map<String, dynamic>
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#dart

Comment: Thanks for help your are rigth it's work perfectly but giving me an error ... The method 'data' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: data()

Comment: add a bang operator. snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>